# Duplicating tool bar on xamrin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamrian forms I have a problem in that when I am calling my main page from my Login form its duplicating the toolbar.

In My app.xml I am sing the following

```
public static Page GetMainPage()
{
        return new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        //return new ExamplePage ();
}
```

And before anyone says this is a minimal example I didnt want to show all my login code obv reasons.

```
 void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        var isValid = true;
        if (isValid)
        {
             Application.Current.MainPage = App.GetMainPage();               

        }
        else
        {
            messageLabel.Text = "Login failed";
            passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Login.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DeliveryDriver.Views.LoginPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Sign Up"  />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Username" />
            <Entry x:Name="usernameEntry" Placeholder="username" />
            <Label Text="Password" />
            <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" IsPassword="true" />
            <Button Text="Login"  Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked"/>
            <Label x:Name="messageLabel" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My Main Page xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:DeliveryDriver.Views"
            x:Class="DeliveryDriver.Views.MainPage">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Jobs">
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:JobsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

        <NavigationPage Title="Items Test">
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:ItemsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

        <NavigationPage Title="About">
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_about.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:AboutPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

I cahnges my app.cs call to my login page as follows as this was suggested.

```
 public App ()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
 }
```

You can clearly see the problem in the image below the content toolbar is duplicated.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nesting NavigationPages in your navigation stack, which isn't what you want to do. GetMainPage() returns a NavigationPage with a child of MainPage. MainPage itself is TabbedPage, and each of its children is a NavigationPage.  Each visible layer of NavigationPage will display a toolbar, which is why you're seeing that.

Best practice with TabbedPage is to use it as the root of your navigation stack, and have NavigationPage instances (or ContentPage instances) as its children. So just do this to clean up the navigation stack, and the extra toolbar should disappear:

```
public static Page GetMainPage()
{
        return new MainPage();
}
```

Comment: I relieased that after a few hours testing lol is their any navigation drawers yet for forms 3.0